# Processing input expression for equation in C

Tags: c

It is easy to make a program which accepts coefficients for a quadratic equation and solves it. But I want to extend it a little bit. I want to give the user freedom to enter a equation of a single variable of his choice(let's restrict the order to 2).

Talking about C-language, I want the user to input,

```
ax^2+bx+c=0
```

And now I want to make the program to determine the coefficients directly from the input.

I thought of taking the input in a string, according to my idea I want to break these string in 3 parts. To put everything before 'x^2' appears in one string, leave the '+' , put every number we get into another string before 'x' appears and lastly omitting the '+' put the last constant in another string.

Simply I want to determine the coefficients, For higher orders too.

I am not getting any idea about this, please someone show me some guidance :)

Comment: You are on the right track. Hint: ASCII values.

Comment: Methinks this is essentially an extension of the expression parser example in K & R.

Comment: Read about the [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), and how to write a parser. Essentially you convert your expression into reverse polish notation and then evaluating becomes very simple. The tricky part of course, is to convert the expression ;).

Comment: Thanks , I am now trying to design the program. The reverse polish notation is a new thing that added to my knowledge and I would edit if I get my code right

Comment: He just wants the coefficients. The user does not want to evaluate the expression. Postfix and prefix notations help in expression evaluation using stack.

Comment: @PrajjwalSrivastav How do I store the ascii value of a charcter in an integer ? there seems to be no specific function for that . I can print ascii values but how to store, suppose I want to store the ascii value of str[3] inside an integer 'i'. which function should I use ?

Comment: `char c = 'A';
int x = c;
printf("%d",x); //output is the ASCII value of A, 52`

You can directly use `c` in `printf` with `%d` as the format specifier to get same result.

Comment: A general technique parsing strings are regular expressions, just in case you have not heard of them. This will provide you with lots of stuff to read ;)